# How the the value of the search variable carry to the new template?

Tags: php, twig

I am using boltCMS and basically they have this default simplistic default theme, the search bar is contained in the `_topbar.twig` file , which is basically the following:

```
<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    {{ menu(template = 'partials/_sub_menu.twig') }}
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <form method="get" action="{{ path('search') }}" id="searchform-inline" enctype="text/plain">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><input type="search" value="{% if search is defined %}{{ search|escape }}{% endif %}" placeholder="{{ __('general.phrase.search-ellipsis') }}" name="search"></li>
        <li><button type="submit" class="button secondary">{{ __('general.phrase.search') }}</button></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code for `_topbar.twig` can be seen [here](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.1/theme/base-2016/partials/_topbar.twig).

Now when somebody enters a term in the search bar and clicks on search button, how exactly is the `search` variable set to the value of the search term and how exactly does the value of the `search` variable carry to the new search.twig template?

The `search.twig` template is [here](https://github.com/bolt/bolt/blob/release/3.1/theme/base-2016/search.twig).